# Is it allowed to assign values to module inputs?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is assigning a value on a module input permitted?  I thought this would not be the case.  I made example codes and tested these through EDA Playground.

Both of these turned out to have errors.

But, why it is not permitted?

```
module test(
  input a,b,c
);
  a=1; b=0; c=1;
endmodule
```

```
module test(
  input wire a,b,c
);
  a=1; b=0; c=1;
endmodule
```

These are the codes I tested.

Comment: the code you showed is syntactically wrong and the errors have nothing to do with assignments to inputs. As for the latter: what is the reason that you want to do such an assignment? You may assign, but results might not be that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `a=1; b=0; c=1;` is illegal because assignment operations must be part of an `assign` statement or within procedural blocks such as `always`, `initial`, `task`, and `function`. Inline assignments when declaring the signal as it is allowed because it treated as an inferred `assign` for net types (e.g. `wire`) and `initial` for non-net types (ex `reg` and `integer`).

Generally you should not drive a modules inputs within its definition. Doing so often results in driver conflict. The inputs should be driving at a higher level.

SystemVerilog allows default values for inputs as defined in [IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 23.2.2.4 *Default port values*. If the default is not specfied, then the default is high impedance (`'z`). It will only use the default value if the input is not connected for the module instance.

```
module test(
  input a=1'b2,b=2'b0,c=2'b1
);
endmodule
```

Be aware that the default port value feature may not be implemented by all simulators, synthesizers, or other EDA tools. You will need to run tests with your tools.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to show the error to make sure the problem you are seeing is exactly from the code posted.

Both code examples you show are identical. `wire` is the implicit signal kind for an `input` port.

There are a number of reasons the procedural assignment statements you show are illegal. You cannot have procedural assignment statements at the top level of a module; they need to be inside a procedural block like an `always`, `initial`, `task`, or `function`. And you are not allowed to make procedural assignments to wires. (See [this article](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/))

You are allowed drive a wire with a continuous assignment

```
module test(
  input a,b,c
);
  assign a=1, b=0, c=1;
endmodule
```

Synthesis tools may not allow it, but the Verilog language allows multiple drivers, and the port may be coerced to an `inout`.